# Can I get maven to generate two test jars with different classifiers?

Tags: unit-testing, maven

I have a maven project where I generate some test code for some modules. I'd like this generated test code to be available for testing by other modules. Typically if the module *bar* wants to use the test code of module *foo*, the *foo* module must generate a *foo-tests.jar* and the module *bar* adds a dependency such as:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which is fine, except that I only want to pull in the generated test code of *foo*, not all of *foo*'s unit tests and helper classes (there may be unintended class conflicts, for example). I'd like to define a dependency such as:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <classifier>test-libs</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Typically *maven-jar-plugin* is used to generate the *foo-test* artifact, so I was hoping I could configure that plugin to generate two test artifacts: one that contains the usual test code (unit tests, etc) in *foo-tests* and one that contains the generated code in *foo-test-libs*, using two different classifiers, e.g.:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-test-jar</id>
      <phase>package</package>
      <goals><goal>test-jar</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>... all the generated code ...</excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-test-libs-jar</id>
      <phase>package</package>
      <goals><goal>test-jar</goal></goals>
      <classifier>test-libs</classifier>
      <configuration>
        <includes>... all the generated code ...</includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem here is that, unlike the *jar* goal, the *test-jar* goal of *maven-jar-plugin* does not support the *classifier* element. I assume the goal uses the *test* classifier by default, so I cannot generated two test jars with different classifiers.

I am wondering if there's a good way of splitting the test jars for a maven module? If all else fails, I can go back to adding dependencies on the complete test jar, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

(And I know that using *classifier* is frowned upon, but I'm not sure if it can be avoided here ...)

Comment: When you answer your own question it's best to do so in an actual answer, rather than editing your question into a state that doesn't need an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. I was in a rush last night so didn't get time to move the edits to an answer. But I have done so now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out, using a combination of *maven-antrun-plugin* to create multiple test jar files (using the *jar* task), and *build-helper-maven-plugin* to attach the generated jar file as artifacts to the project.

1. Generate test jar files.

I use *maven-antrun-plugin* combined with the ant *jar* task to split my test code:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <!-- The test-libs jar contains all test code in the x.y.z package. -->
          <jar destfile="${project.build.directory}/artifacts/test-libs/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
               basedir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes"
               includes="x/y/z/**/*.class"/>
          <!-- The tests jar contains all test code exception the x.y.z package. -->
          <jar destfile="${project.build.directory}/artifacts/tests/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
               basedir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes"
               excludes="x/y/z/**/*.class"/>
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that I had to use the same name *${project.build.finalName}.jar* for each generated jar file (this is important later) so I put each jar file into its own directory:

- *target/artifacts/test-libs/foo.jar*
- *target/artifacts/tests/foo.jar*

  2. Attaching the jar files to the project.

Generating the jar files is only the first step. The jar files need to be attached to the maven project so that they will be installed. For this the *build-helper-maven-plugin* is required. This allows attaching of files as artifacts, where each file has a location, a type, and a classifier. Here the type is *jar* and the classifier will be *tests* or *test-libs* as appropriate:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-test-jars</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals><goal>attach-artifact</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifacts>
          <!-- Attach the test-libs artifact. -->
          <artifact>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/artifacts/test-libs/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>test-libs</classifier>
          </artifact>
          <!-- Attach the tests artifact. -->
          <artifact>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/artifacts/tests/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
          </artifact>
        </artifacts>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this I now see the following output:

```
[INFO] Installing ...\target\artifacts\test-libs\foo-1.0.jar to ...\foo\1.0\foo-1.0-test-libs.jar
[INFO] Installing ...\target\artifacts\tests\foo-1.0.jar to ...\foo\1.0\foo-1.0-tests.jar
[INFO] Installing ...\target\foo-1.0.jar to ...\foo\1.0\foo-1.0.jar
```

My other projects can now add dependencies on either *foo-test.jar* or *foo-test-lib.jar* as required. Huzzah!